# Как сделать что бы изображение всегда появлялось под мышкой?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать что бы при клике изображение всегда появлялось под мышкой в заданном блоке?

```js
document.getElementById('get').onclick = function(e) {
  var x = e.offsetX == undefined ? e.layerX : e.offsetX;
  var y = e.offsetY == undefined ? e.layerY : e.offsetY;
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/57d55366a6bde157194dc91b.png';
  img.id = 'go';
  img.style.width = "20px";
  img.style.height = "20px";
  img.style.top = "" + y + "px";
  img.style.left = "" + x + "px";
  img.style.position = "relative";
  get.appendChild(img);
};

function sty() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('get');
  while (elem.firstChild) {
    elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="1ro" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;float: left;margin-left: 30px;background: #1E90FF"></div>
<div id="get" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;float: left;margin-left: 30px;background: #1d9e74"></div>
<input type="button" value="Очистить" onclick="sty()">
```

Надо что бы картинка появлялась в тех координатах которые при клики у мышке в блоке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде такого? Ваш же код с минимальными изменениями.

```js
document.getElementById('get').onclick = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX == undefined ? e.layerX : e.clientX; // client вместо offset (так должно даже при прокрученной странице работать вроде бы)
  var y = e.clientY == undefined ? e.layerY : e.clientY; // то же самое
  var get = document.getElementById('get'); // определяем get, иначе откуда в последней строчке он возьмется?
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/57d55366a6bde157194dc91b.png';
  // img.id = 'go'; нельзя одинаковые id делать
  img.style.width = "20px";
  img.style.height = "20px";
  img.style.top = "" + y - 10 + "px"; // - половина высоты картинки
  img.style.left = "" + x - 10 + "px"; // - половина высоты картинки
  img.style.position = "absolute"; // абсолютное позиционирование
  get.appendChild(img);
};

function sty() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('get');
  while (elem.firstChild) {
    elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="1ro" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;float: left;margin-left: 30px;background: #1E90FF"></div>
<div id="get" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;float: left;margin-left: 30px;background: #1d9e74"></div>
<input type="button" value="Очистить" onclick="sty()">
```